# Just run single test instead of the whole suite?

Tags: go

I have a test suite for a Go package that implements a dozen tests. Sometimes, one of the tests in the suite fails and I'd like to re-run that test individually to save time in debugging process. Is this possible or do I have to write a separate file for this every time?

Comment: `go run -run regexp` will only run tests whos name matches the regular expression. [docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags)

Comment: Thanks. But should be `go test -run`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use the `go test -run` flag to run a specific test. The flag is documented in
the [testing flags section](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags) of the [go tool](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) documentation:

```
-run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
    expression.
```

Comment: And as a `regexp`, if you want to run a precise test (and no other tests that may share that name as a prefix) - use regexp's first and last anchors e.g. `go test '-run=^TestMyTest$'`

Comment: If you are using subtests, keep in mind that you are passing a slash-separated list of regular expressions, so something like `go test -r "TestFoo/^bar$/baz` is valid.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. I got the error `...build constraints exclude all Go files in...` Instead, I needed to do `go test -run=TestMyTest ./...`

Answer (score 50):

In case someone that is using Ginkgo BDD framework for Go will have the same problem, this could be achieved in that framework by marking test spec as focused ([see docs](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#focused-specs)), by prepending `F` before `It`, `Context` or `Describe`functions.

So, if you have spec like:

```
    It("should be idempotent", func() {
```

You rewrite it as:

```
    FIt("should be idempotent", func() {
```

And it will run exactly that one spec:

```
[Fail] testing Migrate setCurrentDbVersion [It] should be idempotent 
...
Ran 1 of 5 Specs in 0.003 seconds
FAIL! -- 0 Passed | 1 Failed | 0 Pending | 4 Skipped
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but inside 'var _ = g.Describe(...), but it it isn't working, and still runs the other tests. Do you have any idea why? I'm a bit new to Go.

Comment: @JoshuaOliphant For me it happens when there are more than one package with tests, and it runs tests in all packages. Then, even in one package tests are focused - it runs other packages. But to figure out your problem I need more details.

Comment: Just F it! Super easy to remember, nice one ginkgo

Answer (score 38):

Given a test:

```
func Test_myTest() {
    //...
}
```

Run only that test with:

```
go test -run Test_myTest path/to/pkg/mypackage
```

Comment: This is quite helpful, I didn't know what should be expressed with RegExp but this sample just made me understand in 1s

Answer (score 33):

Simple and reliable:

```golang
go test -run TestMyFunction ./...
```

More on `./...` :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28031651/5726621

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you - simple and straight to the point

Comment: How on earth this is not an accepted answer?

Comment: IMO, the best answer.

Answer (score 17):

Say your test suite is structured as following:

```
type MyTestSuite struct {
  suite.Suite
}

func TestMyTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
  suite.Run(t, new(MyTestSuite))
}

func (s *MyTestSuite) TestMethodA() {
}
```

To run a specific test of test suite in go, you need to use: `-testify.m`.

```
 go test -v <package> -run ^TestMyTestSuite$ -testify.m TestMethodA
```

More simply, if the method name is unique to a package, you can always run this

```
go test -v <package> -testify.m TestMethodA
```

Answer (score 13):

```
go test -v <package> -run <TestFunction>
```