# What do three dots "./..." mean in Go command line invocations?

Tags: go

If you run Golang tests on Travis CI, it will [download all of your dependencies with three dots](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/):

```
go get -d -v ./... && go build -v ./...
```

What does `./...` indicate or expand to there? I've done some research but it doesn't seem to be a Unix convention.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

From the command `go help packages`:

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards,
>   each of which can match any string, including the empty string and
>   strings containing slashes.  Such a pattern expands to all package
>   directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the
>   patterns.  As a special case, x/... matches x as well as x's subdirectories.
>   For example, net/... expands to net and packages in its subdirectories.

Comment: So it's similar to the `**` wildcard implemented by some shells.

Comment: Conceptually similar to `**` for sure, the cool part is that it's only files relevant to `go`, and that it works the same across platforms and shells. I'm pretty new to Go, and this pleases me ^__^

Answer (score 90):

```
go [command] ./...
```

Here `./` tells to start from the current folder, `...` tells to go down recursively.

**For Example:**

```
go list ...
```

In any folder lists all the packages, including packages of the standard library first followed by external libraries in your go workspace.

Comment: ahhh That is why `go build ...` take some time (about a minute or more... don't recall), it was compiling every package, right?

Comment: @Victor caution that `...` is different from `./...`. I spent a day trying chasing errors in my `go test` and `go get` commands before learning this. Then all the errors were magically solved.

Comment: @soxsupportsthemods I learn the hard way too... I ran `go build ...` and spend a LOT of time... after that.. .using `go list ...` I see  every package present in my computer listed and then I understood that every package was compiled......  takes some time, but it was learned!

Comment: I figured this is what it means, but I can't for the life of me find where this is documented.  This is non-standard (e.g., not glob syntax), so must be a feature of the compiler.  Do you know where this might be documented, or how to search for more on this?