# Go get not fetching all dependencies

Tags: go, package-management

I am using go 1.5.1 on Windows 8.1 64-bit. I do not have `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT` set in my environment. I have the latest version of git and bazaar installed.

I am trying to get the `gomniauth` package:

```
go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth
```

Even though the process completes without any error, a lot of dependencies aren't pulled in.

For example, when compiling my app (which depends on gomniauth), I get these errors:

```
..\github.com\stretchr\codecs\xml\simple_xml_codec.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/clbanning/x2j" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\github.com\clbanning\x2j (from $GOROOT)
    C:\work\src\github.com\clbanning\x2j (from $GOPATH)
..\github.com\stretchr\codecs\msgpack\msgpack_codec.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/ugorji/go/codec" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\github.com\ugorji\go\codec (from $GOROOT)
    C:\work\src\github.com\ugorji\go\codec (from $GOPATH)
..\github.com\stretchr\codecs\bson\bson_codec.go:5:2: cannot find package "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\labix.org\v2\mgo\bson (from $GOROOT)
    C:\work\src\labix.org\v2\mgo\bson (from $GOPATH)
```

It seems to pull in the direct dependencies for `gomniauth`, but doesn't pull in the dependencies of the dependencies. I have gone and deleted the `stretchr` folder from my `GOPATH/src` as well as `GOPATH/pkg`, but after running `go get` many times, it is still not pulling in the any dependencies beyond the second level.

I am 100% confident there are no network issues on my end. I can  access those github repos using my browser or curl.

Comment: Are you sure these are dependencies of `gominiauth`? If yes: Why are you sure?

Comment: By looking at the sources of `gomniauth` and its dependencies. `gomniauth` depends on `stretchr/codecs` which depends on `clganning/x2j`, `ugorji/go/codec` and `labix.org/v2/mgo/bson`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change directory to your project and then try `go get ./...`
E.g.:

```
cd C:\work\src\github.com\stretchr\gomniauth
go get ./...
```

Or just `go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/...` as **Amit Kumar Gupta** suggested

Comment: Or just `go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/...`

Comment: `go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/...` Works for me. What does the `...` do? Doesn't appear in the docs for `go get`: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies Also, why the need for `...`? Wouldn't people installing things with `go get` want all the dependencies so that the packages work?

Comment: It's a wildcard. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031603/what-do-three-dots-mean-in-go-command-line-invocations

Comment: That makes sense, but why would the default behavior not automatically expand all the import paths so that all the dependencies are installed?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta when I run 'go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/...' I     `get go: missing Bazaar command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd package labix.org/v2/mgo/bson: exec: "bzr": executable file not found in     %PATH%` I just installed Bazaar and set %PATH% and I am not sure what is going on?

Comment: @hellyale It seems to me that you should install Bazaar first

Comment: @RoninDev turns out I needed to restart my computer for the install to complete 'doh

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the [bzr package](http://bazaar.canonical.com/).

After adding it using `dnf install bzr` and running @RoninDev suggestion it worked as expected:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/stretchr/gomniauth
go get ./...
```